# Validation script stopped working after adding ajax insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I had a working form validation script, but when I added an ajax script that inserts data with the form without refreshing, the validation script stopped working.

Normally the script would stop the form from submitting because something was wrong, but now it submits always even if there is nothing in the form fields.

So the query happens before the script can stop it, is there a way to run the query after validation?

My index page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //insert record
        $('#insert').click(function(){
            var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
            var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
            var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();

            //syntax - $.post('filename', {data}, function(response){});
            $.post('action.php',{action: "submit", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam, telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
                $('#result').html(res);
            });
            document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!';        
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<table>
<td>
    <form name="form">
        <tr>
        <p class="names">Voornaam:</p> <p><input type="text" name="voornaam" id="voornaam"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Achternaam:</p> <p><input type="text" name="achternaam" id="achternaam"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Telefoonnummer:</p> <p><input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnummer"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Emailadres:</p> <p><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <input class="knop" type="button" name="submit" value="Opsturen" id="insert">
        </tr>
    </form>
</td>
</table>
<br>
<div id="berichten">

</div>

<script>
var validator = new FormValidator('form', [{
    name: 'voornaam',
    display: 'Voornaam',    
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'achternaam',
    display: 'achternaam', 
    rules: 'required'
},{
    name: 'telefoonnummer',
    display: 'telefoon', 
    rules: 'required|numeric'
},{
    name: 'email',
    display: 'email', 
    rules: 'required|valid_email'
}], function(errors, event) {
    /*cache DOM node*/
    var berichten = document.getElementById('berichten');

    /*reset html content*/
    berichten.innerHTML = '';

    /*add errors*/
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
            berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
        }

    }

});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My action page:

```
<?php
    //connect to db
include ('connection.php');

    //if insert key is pressed then do insertion
    if($_POST['action'] == 'submit'){

        $voornaam  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['voornaam']);
        $achternaam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['achternaam']);
        $email  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $telefoonnummer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefoonnummer']);

        $sql = "insert into 
           `form` (`id`,`voornaam`, `achternaam`, `email`, `telefoonnummer`) 
            values ('','".$voornaam."', '".$achternaam."', '".$email."', '".$telefoonnummer."')";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if($query){
            echo "Toegevoegd!";
        }else {
            echo "Er is iets fout gegaan.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (errors.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
      berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
   }//end for each
  }else{
       AjaxInsert(); // add validation code here or convert your click event into function
  }

  function AjaxInsert(){
        var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
        var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
        var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        //syntax - $.post('filename', {data}, function(response){});
        $.post('action.php',{action: "submit", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam, telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
        });
        document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!'; 
  }
```